# Select a UITextField with Frank

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, frank

I am using

```
When /^I touch the textfield marked "([^\\"]*)"$/ do |textfield_marked|
    touch "view:'UITextField' marked'#{textfield_marked}'"
end
```

and this is the error I get

```
 frankly_map view:'UITextField' marked'Domain' touch failed because: invalid selector
  no paramater found at position 25 in string "view:'UITextField' marked'Domain'" (RuntimeError)
  ./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:18:in `/^I touch the textfield marked "([^\\"]*)"$/'
  features/login.feature:8:in `When I touch the textfield marked "Domain"'
```

I verify that the UITextField is there before hand, and it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a colon after "marked"

try

touch "view:'UITextField' marked:'#{textfield_marked}'"